# Problem installing openni_kinect

Tags: ros, depth-image, openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I started using ROS last week and tried installing openni_kinect. I followed the steps here:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect

Everything seems to work properly until I get to step 4 when I start to compile. I get an error:

[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/depth_image_proc.dir/src/nodelets/register.o
/home/drcool/openni_kinect/openni_kinect/depth_image_proc/src/nodelets/register.cpp: In member function ‘void depth_image_proc::RegisterNodelet::imageCb(const ImageConstPtr&, const CameraInfoConstPtr&, const CameraInfoConstPtr&)’:

**/home/drcool/openni_kinect/openni_kinect/depth_image_proc/src/nodelets/register.cpp:117:5: error: ‘Matrix3x3’ is not a member of ‘tf’
/home/drcool/openni_kinect/openni_kinect/depth_image_proc/src/nodelets/register.cpp:117:20: error: ‘R’ was not declared in this scope**

**make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/depth_image_proc.dir/src/nodelets/register.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/drcool/openni_kinect/openni_kinect/depth_image_proc/build' make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/depth_image_proc.dir/all] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/drcool/openni_kinect/openni_kinect/depth_image_proc/build'
make[1]: *** **[all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/drcool/openni_kinect/openni_kinect/depth_image_proc/build'****

The bolded section states the specific error. Before I began installing this I installed the nao stacks for ROS located here:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao/Installation

My current system is Ubuntu 11.10 oneiric, and I did a full desktop install of ROS electric. Any help with this problem would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12632/problem-installing-openni_kinect/) by [famlyguy1989](https://answers.ros.org/users/1643/famlyguy1989/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're using ROS on Ubuntu, you shouldn't have to install the drivers from source; just do:

`sudo apt-get install ros-electric-openni-kinect`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5